# Are there any methods for android development that can find the maximum units on screen?

Tags: java, android, methods

I'm drawing a rectangle and I'm trying to figure out the maximum dimensions of the display I'm using without trial and error. I know the top left corner is (0,0), but is there a method that retrieves the outer edge coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity you can call:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
display.getWidth(); // returns width
display.getHeight(); // returns height
```

This will give you the maximum dimensions of the current display.